# How to do conditional sum?

Tags: excel

[image]

Want to add 1000 after every second day. If the day is 3 than 1000 should be added after every 3rd day if 1, 1000 should be added after every day. Any formula that can help in achieving this requirment in excel

Comment: Check if the number is exactly divisible by 3, if so then add...

Comment: Dont know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=(INT((ROW(A1)-1)/$B$1)+1)*$B$2
```

[image]